# How to check if any check box is checked in a table using jQuery?

Tags: java, jquery

Can anyone help me how to check if any of the check box is checked in a table(I am using custom component for table). First column in the table has check boxes. I want to find if any one of them was checked. I have something for the text field(to find particular text) but it is not working with checkbox.

```
$( "#mainFormId\\:tableId tr").each( function( index ) {
                    var columnText = $( this ).children().eq(0).text();
                    if(othernumber==columnText){
   }
 });
```

Please help me thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML or a jsfiddle demo?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `:checked` selector:

```
$('#mainFormId\\:tableId tr').find(':checked').each(...);
```

Or since you're using `children()` try with (this only search with the DOM element childs):

```
$('#mainFormId\\:tableId tr').children(':checked').each(...);
```

Comment: `:checked` selector gets the checked objects, try this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0td26vhg/